# Wordpress key Duplication Error

Tags: database, wordpress

I just uploaded my database onto a remote server, however I am having a database connection error. As all configurations were fine, I contacted my host and they said the connection is fine however I have a lot of key duplication error. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Wipe the database and re-import the sql file. Depending on the host, they may have had a `wp_` database already uploaded so when you're uploading your database there are duplicate entries. Or, if your db failed to upload once and you tried it again, there could be some overlap there as well.

Comment: Thank you very much that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wipe the database and re-import the sql file. Depending on the host, they may have had a wp_ database already uploaded so when you're uploading your database there are duplicate entries. Or, if your db failed to upload once and you tried it again, there could be some overlap there as well.

**This is the answer**